# Angular2: Upload large file

Tags: node.js, angular, express, file-upload, angular-file-upload

I am using Angular2 and nodeJS (loopback) for my application. I want to upload a large file to my backend server as I have not tried much code for file uploading.

So can someone help me with some efficient way to make a large file upload fast?

Also as per my understanding Angular works on the client side so file uploading will be done by nodeJs, right?

Another thing will breaking the large file into chunks and then uploading will help?

If yes then how will those multiple chunks are can be merged at backend node (loopback).

Comment: see the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723536/uploading-large-file-to-nodejs-webserver

Comment: see the link https://pagep.net/2018/03/31/how-to-handle-large-file-upload-with-nodejs-express-server/